# Analogues of direct sum and direct product in topology

Tags: general-topology

If we have modules $(M_i)_{i\in I}$, then we construct two modules with some universal property, namely direct sum and direct product; they are non-isomorphic when $I$ is infinite.

In topology, I saw that there is a notion of direct product of topological spaces, which is quite analogous to direct product of modules.

Isn't there any analogue of *direct sum of modules* in topology? (I could not find it in Munkres' book; I may have been overlooked, but then please tell the reference.)

Comment: The direct sum of modules is a coproduct in category of modules. The coproduct in the category of topological spaces is disjoint union. This structure will satisfy analogous universal property.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unsurprisingly, it depends on what you consider an analogue of a direct sum.

As pointed out in a comment, the direct sum of modules is the [coproduct](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coproduct) in the category of modules, so a natural analogue would be the coproduct in the category of topological spaces. This is the [disjoint union](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disjoint_union_(topology)) of the underlying sets, equipped with the topology given by unions of (the images under inclusion of) the given open sets.

However, especially since you refer to Munkres, which makes use of both [direct sums of groups](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Direct_sum_of_groups) and [free products of groups](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_product), it’s worth mentioning that this is not the only way to form analogues of direct sums. A direct sum of groups is formed much like a direct sum of modules and is thus a natural candidate for “the analogue of direct sums of modules for groups” (so much so that it has the same name, “direct sum”), but it’s not the coproduct in the category of groups (which is the free product).